# Compare elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, filtering

Assume that there are three different points in x-y coordinate like:

```
p1={4, -1};
p2={5, -2};
p3={1, 5};
```

In order to compare these points to each other in a specific criteria, I have first built `List1` which includes the whole possible states:

```
List1={{{4, -1}, {5, -2}}, {{4, -1}, {1, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {5, -2}}};
```

The criteria is:

> If any of these two points has an x value bigger than the x value of the other point and a y value smaller than the y value of the other point, add this point to a different list. Otherwise move on to the next pair of points.
>   Give a number which shows how many times point1 from List1 satisfies the criteria.

In order to clarify the problem :

> first element of `List1` includes two points : `{{4, -1}, {5, -2}}`
>   `point1 = {4, -1}` and `point2 = {5, -2}`. x1 = 4 < x2 = 5 and y1 = -1 > y2 = -2. So point `{5, -2}` dominates point `{4, -1}` : ( 5>4 and -2<-1 )
>
> Now put point {5, -2} in a list and give a number which shows how many times point {5, -2} satisfy the criteria.

The final results have to be like bellow:

> ```
> DominatePoint1 = {{5, -2},2}
> DominatePoint2 = {{4, -1},1}
> DominatePoint3 = {{1, 5},0}
> ```

How can this be implemented in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a very direct approach to the problem:

```
list1 = Subsets[{p1, p2, p3}, {2}];
f = Module[{x1 = #[[1, 1]], y1 = #[[1, 2]], x2 = #[[2, 1]], y2 = #[[2, 2]]},
     If[x1 > x2 && y1 < y2, 
      #[[1]], 
      #[[2]]]
     ] &;
```

and then

```
Tally[f /@ list1]
```

However, I'm not sure if the alternative is correct, as it wasn't specified.
If you also need the points with zero counts:

```
Reverse@SortBy[
  Map[{#, Count[f /@ list1, #]} &, Union@ArrayFlatten[list1, 1]], 
 Last]
```

---

**Edit: for the clarified selection criteria the former function definition is no longer correct, but the following are:**

More complex decisions can be implemented using `Which` instead of `If`, e.g.

```
f2 = Module[{x1 = #[[1, 1]], y1 = #[[1, 2]], x2 = #[[2, 1]], y2 = #[[2, 2]]},
      Which[
       x1 > x2 && y1 < y2, #[[1]],
       x2 > x1 && y2 < y1, #[[2]]
      ]
     ] &;
```

will return the point that satisfies the criterion and `Null` if none does.

---

An alternative approach is the use of a conditioned function definition:

```
f3[l_List]:=l[[1]] /; l[[1,1]] > l[[2,1]] && l[[1,2]] < l[[2,2]]
f3[l_List]:=l[[2]] /; l[[2,1]] > l[[1,1]] && l[[2,2]] < l[[1,2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach

```
Clear[dominateCount]

dominateCount[points : {_, _} ..] := 
 Module[{pairs, dominatePick, pickedPoints}, 
  pairs = Subsets[{points}, {2}];
  dominatePick[p1_List, p2_List] := Switch[p1 - p2,
    {_?NonNegative, _?NonPositive}, 
    p1, {_?NonPositive, _?NonNegative}, p2,
    _, Null];
  pickedPoints = dominatePick @@@ pairs;
  DeleteCases[
   Append[Tally@pickedPoints, 
    Append[Complement[{points}, pickedPoints], 0]], {Null, _}]
  ]

dominateCount[p1, p2, p3]     
(* {{{5, -2}, 2}, {{4, -1}, 1}, {{1, 5}, 0}} *)
```

Comment: will edit this later. Pasting from WolframCloud is horrible.

Comment: Don't worry, saved you the trouble. +1.

Comment: For `p1 = {4, 0}; p2 = {5, 0}; p3 = {10, 0}; p4 = {10, 1};` this code doesn't provide the correct output `{{{10, 1}, 0}, {{10, 0}, 0}, {{5, 0}, 0}, {{4, 0}, 0}}`

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks so much! I edited my answer again to fix an issue in it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I well understand the criterion, because for much more points my results are different from those obtained with f1 and f2 suggested by @Karsten 7. 
However, they agree with those obtained using dominateCount written by RunnyKine.
So, I would have your suggestions about my solution.

```
dominate[l : {{_, _} ..}] :=
Module[{a, b},
       a = Sort[l]; 
       b = SortBy[l, Last]; 
       Map[{#, Length[Intersection[Cases[{b}, {___, #, vals__} :> vals], 
                                   Cases[{a}, {vals___, #, ___} :> vals]]]}&, b]]

dominate[{p1, p2, p3}]
gives
{{{5, -2}, 2}, {{4, -1}, 1}, {{1, 5}, 0}}
```

Note that dominateCount gives a result counting the frequency of Null, not sure this is needed.
Here is a test of timing for a bigger dataser

```
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = dominate[l];]
{8.901509, Null}
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = dominateCount[l];]
{51.900968, Null}
```

For a big dataset my approach seems to be faster.

Comment: It's really brilliant!!

Answer (score 2):

I find the question confusing but piggybacking on Karsten's apparently correct answer you might consider:

```
p = {{4, -1}, {5, -2}, {1, 5}};
list1 = Subsets[p, {2}];

f4[{a_, b_}] := Null[, a, b,][[ Sign[a - b].{1, -1} ]]

# - {0, 1} & /@ Tally @ Join[p, f4 /@ list1]
```

> ```
> {{{4, -1}, 1}, {{5, -2}, 2}, {{1, 5}, 0}}
> ```

A count of `Null` represents any case that did not match the pattern to be either `a` or `b`.

Comment: I wonder how it is possible to run the code for some identical points in `p` list. For example :
`p={{4, -1}, {5, -2}, {1, 5}, {1, 5}};` .Accordingly the correct answer is : `{{{4, -1}, 1}, {{5, -2}, 2}, {{1, 5}, 0},{{1, 5}, 0}}`.